# Follow original HTTP Method - What's the java fix?

Tags: java, rest, http, postman, okhttp

Postman has a setting which corrects the method on calls which redirect.

[Postman Settings : Follow original HTTP Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEpqx.png)

> Follow original HTTP Method: Redirect with the original HTTP method
> instead of the default behavior of redirecting with GET.

How can we implement this in Java code? I am using OKHttp. I am also open to using other libs if necessary.

Error:{"detail": "Method "GET" not allowed."}

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("job_id","z5G7h3l6a1kMvyS65NP3c0a2-MRSuDJL0EWa7zDjsGs=")
  .addFormDataPart("firstname","Jhon")
  .addFormDataPart("lastname","Doe")
  .addFormDataPart("email","john.doe@gmail.com")
  .addFormDataPart("city","Dallas")
  .addFormDataPart("state","TX")
  .addFormDataPart("country","US")
  .addFormDataPart("mobile_number","555-5555")
  .addFormDataPart("file_name","jd.pdf")
  .addFormDataPart("resume","/C:/Users/test/Downloads/test.pdf",
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
    new File("/C:/Users/test/Downloads/test.pdf")))
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://api.ceipal.com/xx-yy-zzz/ApplyJobWithOutRegistration")
  .method("POST", body)
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

This results in these calls in the interceptor:

```
url: https://api.ceipal.com/xxx-yyy-zzz/ApplyJobWithOutRegistration 
method:POST
header:Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=21938c2b-0d98-4851-8532-a91ba219491d
Content-Length: 157614
Host: api.ceipal.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/4.9.1

url: https://api.ceipal.com/xxx-yyy-zzz/ApplyJobWithOutRegistration/ 
method:GET
header:Host: api.ceipal.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/4.9.1
```

as the redirect replaces the POST with GET the call responds with this error:

Error:{"detail": "Method "GET" not allowed."}

When I try this call in Postman,

- Without the setting I get a response: Error:{"detail": "Method "GET" not allowed."}
- With the setting turned on - {"status": 201, "success": 0, "message": "You have already applied for this job."}